# Weird JS Object Keys; Getters and Setters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, get, set, getter

Can someone please explain how this is valid JS.

Namely the get and set that are found within the objutil.mixin.  I would think that the object would have to have key value pairs, but it seems like the get and set are either renaming or firing the functions.  I don't really know how it is doing this, and I can't find precedence for the naming convention in the code.

Also, kind of a side note, this works I'm just curious as to why it works and if there is some rule for key names in JS that i don't know about.

```
objutil.mixin({
    get cache() { // <---here
        return cache;
    }, 

    set configuration(config) { //<---here
        assert.ok(config && thing.isObject(config), 'expected configuration to be an object.');
        configuration = config;
    },

    register: function (name, factory) {        
        assert.ok(factory && thing.isFunction(factory), 'expected a factory function to register.');

        cache[name] = factory;

        return exports;
    }
}, exports);
```

Comment: Have you read the MDN for getters and setters? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I google searched "is get reserved in javascript" and got this... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar   so now I look like the lame that didnt google :|

Comment: to be fair I probably didn't do enough googling